# Postgis order ST_INTERSECTION(polygon, linestring) distance query results by the intersections order

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Given a query that calculates distances of ST_INTERSECTION of a linestring with many polygons (stored in the polygon_column in the PolygonTable):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
    ST_LENGTH(
      ST_INTERSECTION(
        po.polygon_column,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122 48,-122 38,-122 37,...)', 4326))::geography)) 
  AS route_length, po.polygon_name 
FROM PolygonTable po 
GROUP by po.polygon_name;
```

The results are returned ordered by the PolygonTable polygon_name. How can I order the results in the order the line intersects them?

That is, if I have polygons A,B,C,D, and the line string goes through them in the order of B,A,C,D, I'd like my results to be

```
  route_length     | polygon_name 
------------------+----------
 123.391961613962 |        B
 321.511826869426 |        A
  123.69306414636 |        C
  321.69306414636 |        D
```

Comment: ORDER BY route_length DESC

Comment: Hi. That's not it. Sorry if the explanation is not clear: I need it ordered by the order the line goes through polygons, not by the route length

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution. It's basic and won't catch all the possible edge-cases, but it's a start :-)

I've only tested it on a simple use case (one line passing through multiple buildings) using **QGIS Db Manager**, a database layer (from postgres) and a scratch line layer.

QGIS uses spatialite to do these because I'm mixing postgres and non-postgres sources. The postgis-only version should be very similar (the functions in spatialite and postgis are very similar, just change the names in most cases)

The approach is :-

- find a point of intersection between your line and each polygon
- order them in ascending order of distance from the start of your line.

.

```
with a as (
    select 
        poly.osm_id, -- your polygon ID
        st_pointn(
            st_geometryn(
                intersection(poly.geometry,foo.geometry),1
            ), -- first geometry
            1 -- first point
        )
        as geom 
    from 
        poly, 
        foo -- line layer 
    where 
        intersects(poly.geometry, foo.geometry) 
)
select 
    a.osm_id, -- polygon id
    a.geom     -- intersection point
from
    a, foo
order 
    by length(make_line(st_pointn(foo.geometry,1), a.geom)) asc;
```

Here's the line (layer 'foo') , red stars show where it intersects. Labels are the polygon IDs (I'm using data from OSM here).

[image]

here's the results of the query in QGIS, in order of intersection.

[image]

There appears to be a different number of stars (5) to the number of results (7); that's because the start point is actually in 3 different overlapping polygons, so the first point appears 3 times in the same place).

This is just a starter; it won't catch a lot of edge cases (I haven't tried it with more complex geometries, holes, overlapping and invalid geometries etc.).

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks! I haven't managed to make it work yet, but at least I have a direction to move towards